# asp.net ajax to code behind with parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, computer-science

Please help me, why my code is wrong? I am following along from [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_retrieve_data_from_pagemethod.ashx).

this is my code behind:

```
public static string HelloName(string name)
{
    return "hello, " + name;
}
```

this is my jQuery:

```
$('#Name').click(function () {
    var name = "step";
    //var dataValue = {"name":name};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/HelloName",
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: name }),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (msg) {
            var mes = msg.d;
            console.log(mes);
            $("#Name").text(mes);
        }
    });
});
```

I think I followed the tutorial correctly, but what I get is an HTTP 500 Internal Error when I use Page Inspector/Network.

please help me where is my false and correct this piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the attribute `[WebMethod]` on your `HelloName` method, so your code should look like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HelloName(string name)
{
    return "hello, " + name;
}
```